# SIMPLE HTML DOM get html show not supported by encore

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use SIMPLE HTML DOM. I use `file_get_html` to get the content of a website. However it shows the message: Sorry, your browser is not currently supported by Encore.

Is the problem of that website? How can solve it?

Comment: This is usually a sign that the target website does some kind of user agent checking to reject browsers they consider too old. I don’t know how this class actually tries to load the content of an URL, but if it uses default PHP methods like file_get_contents or similar internally, you can try to set the PHP config option `user_agent` to a user agent of a “modern” browser, f.e. like a Firefox or Chrome. http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CBroe is right, you need to set your user agent for the request. I would consider switching to curl for downloads at this point and using `str_get_html` with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say, haven't seen this kind of error yet... maybe it depends on php version of the webpage, but i doubt that these days some server uses php < 5(well, that could happen...).
Maybe you have referenced something wrong, debug it and see, what it shows.